# get data by percent for each value in table

Tags: c#, sql

i have two tables (last_name table ) and (families table ) that relate to each other by last name ... so every last name in last_name table has many families in families table .. now i want to select 50 percent of families for each last name .. how can i do that please ...

```
select top 50 percent 
    family_id , 
    family_name , 
    last_name 
from 
    families 
where 
    last_name = 'here i want all of last name'
```

after that i want to count all families that i selected from families for each last_name ..
thank you

Comment: Why is there `c#` tag on the question? It looks like sql only question.

Comment: right .. but if C# is required ...

Comment: maybe foreach loop is required to do that .. so i put c# with sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No C# or looping required, the solution below is probably not ideal but should give you a step in the right direction:

```
SELECT F.family_id, F.family_name, F.last_name FROM

(SELECT family_id, family_name, last_name, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY last_name ORDER BY last_name) RowNo
FROM families) F

INNER JOIN (

SELECT last_name, Count(1) as FamCount
FROM families
GROUP BY last_name) GR

ON F.last_name = GR.last_name
AND F.RowNo <= GR.FamCount / 2
```

The idea here is: First inner select gives each family with the same last name a row number. second select gets total count of families for the same last name. And the join gets half of the selection for each family.

Here is the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2900e4/3 the table has 4 families with last name Johnson and 6 with Patterson. And the query returns 2 and 3 families respectfully.

Having this result you can perform additional operations (e.g. group by lastname to get count from the selection)

Comment: thank you very very much Yuriy galanter .. it is perfect and very useful

Comment: hello Yuriy again .. thank you for your code ... just one thing .. when select percent .. i want if selected last name was 3.5 .. i want it 4 and if selected last name was less than 5 in 3.5 .. i want it 3 .. how can i do that .. please

Comment: Could you explain in more details? E.g. If there're 7 families you want 50% to be 4?

Comment: yes i want that .. if 3.5 , 3.6 , 3.7 , 3.8 , 3.9 select 4 families ... and if 3.4 , 3.3 , 3.2 , 3.1 select 3 families .. it is like round method in C#

Comment: TSQL also has a ROUND function you can use. Try replacing last line with this one: `AND F.RowNo <= ROUND(GR.FamCount / 2., 0)` here is a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bb55/10

Comment: ok .. so good .. thank you very much .. but please sorry for questions .. what if i want change the percent like round(GR.famCount * 30 / 100 , 0) .. it dose not work

Comment: Use dot "." in your formula numbers, e.g. `GR.famCount * 30. / 100.` otherwise TSQL performs integer division

Comment: ooook .. thank you very very very much Yuriy .. you are perfect .. i appreciate that

Comment: Glad to help :) this is what SO is for

Comment: hello Yuriy .. how can i chat with you .. please .. i want to explain problem to you .. could you help me please ??

Comment: Sorry I am not always available. If you have another problem just create a separate question so that entire community could help